# Asterisk func_odbc for keep MixMonitor() files on mysql?

Tags: odbc, asterisk, func

I installed asterisk 1.8 with mysql & odbc addons, how can i use func_odbc for  keep MixMonitor() files on mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use MixMonitor to save directly on an SQL table.

Instead, I suggest you to write a script (ex. in PHP) that check new files on /var/spool/asterisk/monitor folder, import file in SQL then remove the file.

You create a new SQL table for "recording" with 2-3 fields (uniqueid, content, filename) and you will be able to link the CDR and recording data easily.

Since all recording files will be saved on an SQL database, you can also create a ramdisk to store files, this will reduce the disk i/o on the server if you have lots of calls ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a table record and use func_odbc.conf

exemple :

func_odbc.conf

```
[R]
dsn=asterisk
prefix=M
writesql=INSERT INTO records (wav,contact,agent,uniqueid) VALUES ('${VAL1}','${VAL2}','${VAL3}','${VAL4}');
```

extensions.conf

```
exten => _0[2345679].,1,NoOp(${CALLERID(num)})
exten => _0[2345679].,n,Set(FILENAME=Poste---${CALLERID(num)}__${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%d-%m-%Y_%Hh%Mm%Ss)}__Appel-Sortant---${EXTEN}_UI-${UNIQUEID})
exten => _0[2345679].,n,Set(M_R()=${FILENAME}\,${EXTEN}\,${CALLERID(num)}\,${UNIQUEID})
exten => _0[2345679].,n,MixMonitor(${FILENAME}.wav,b)
exten => _0[2345679].,n,dial(SIP/gsm2/2${EXTEN})
```